# How can I use <div> list instead of <select> dropdown for a languages switcher?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, sass

I want to use `<div>` instead of `<select>` to list options for a languages switcher. But the problem is i don't know how to pass the value to the jQuery function.

**here is my `<select>` html code**

```
<select id="langSelector">
<option>lang</option>
<option value="de">de</option>
<option value="jp">jp</option>
</select>
```

**What i want to use instead**

```
                    <div id="langSelector" class="dropdown-menu position-absolute" aria-labelledby="language-dropdown">
                        <a value="de" class="dropdown-item d-flex" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="assets/img/de.png" class="flag-width" alt="flag"> <span class="align-self-center">&nbsp;German</span></a>
                        <a value="jp" class="dropdown-item d-flex" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="assets/img/jp.png" class="flag-width" alt="flag"> <span class="align-self-center">&nbsp;Japanese</span></a>
                    </div>
```

**My Jquery Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var l = new LanguageSelector();
    $(function(ready){
     $("#langSelector").change(function() {
         var s = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
         l.setLang(s);
         window.location = '1.html';
     });
     });
    l.parse();
</script>
```

i try to change value"" to data-value"" and option:selected to a:selected > span:selected > a.selected but nothing seems to work

Comment: why don't you like `<select>` and `<option>`?

Comment: Hey @sergeykuznetsov it's due to the **UI** and **limitations** associated with  `<select>` and `<option>` Here's a shot of how it my look like [link](https://ibb.co/M17DyGV)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="langSelector" class="dropdown-menu position-absolute" aria-labelledby="language-dropdown">
    <a data-lang="de" class="dropdown-item d-flex" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="assets/img/de.png" class="flag-width" alt="flag"> <span class="align-self-center">&nbsp;German</span></a>
    <a data-lang="jp" class="dropdown-item d-flex" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="assets/img/jp.png" class="flag-width" alt="flag"> <span class="align-self-center">&nbsp;Japanese</span></a>
</div>

<script>
    var languageSelector = new LanguageSelector();
    $('[data-lang]').on('click', function(){
        var selectedLang = $(this).data('lang');
        languageSelector.setLang(selectedLang);
        
        // DO THE REST OF CODE HERE
        
    });
</script>
```

So store the data in an HTML5 Data Attribute.  Since Im assuming your creating a fake downdown to control useragent styles better (<- my frontends do this alot) we will collect jquery html elements by using the [data-lang] as a selector which will return all the data-lang set elements on the page if you would like to restrict it you may need to use ....

```
$('a[data-lang]')...
```

or

```
$('#langSelector > a[data-lang]')....
```

then use the click listener to return $(this) which will be the current clicked link and access its data('lang') attribute and pass that to lang